OneDrive downloaded files with wrong permissions
We have a Windows Server 2019 that has OneDrive configured. The OneDrive folder is being shared at the same time as a shared drive on users computers. There are a few users that have direct access to OneDrive on their phones and they upload files directly.
We noticed that if one of the users with direct access to OneDrive uploads a file to any folder in OneDrive, on the server that file gets downloaded with only admin rights. Meaning no one else can see the file until someone manually changes the permissions.
I'm not sure we are missing a setting. Any recommendations?

It sounds to me as though you are misusing OneDrive. Using OneDrive to sync a shared folder is not going to work well. OneDrive runs in a user's context, and so any files "downloaded" will be downloaded with the permissions of the user OneDrive is running as. If this is an enterprise environment and you are using OneDrive for business, use Sharepoint Online for shared folders, not the end user's One Drive clients.

We are using Sharepoint, OneDrive app is only being used to synchronize the shared files on the server.

There are a variety of really good synchronization utilities out there that will copy the files as is, or according to the permissions applied to the source or destination folders. OneDrive is just the wrong tool for the job: It is not a file sync utility and cannot function as one.

Just a suggestion, but perhaps rewrite this question. Take the problem you have been using OneDrive to try to solve and present THAT, without the OneDrive bit. It's very likely we can find or suggest solutions that will meet your needs far better than your current setup. However, as you do that, please also consider putting some effort to research and solve this problem yourself, sans OneDrive, and see what you find out. File sync is a pretty common need, and there is a lot of information out there on really good methods to do this.

@Yunxie - Which OneDrive client are you using against SharePoint? Business or personal?

@Ramhound it's Business.

When you say OneDrive is running on your 2019 servers, please explain why and how. Is this a virtual desktop or Terminal Services server, or are you actually trying to do a hybrid SharepointOnline Share/Network File Share thing, because it sounds like you're trying to do some weird hybrid which does, of course, not work.

OneDrive is not a file synchronization tool. You appear to be expecting OneDrive to sync files, but it doesn't, and this misunderstanding is the core of the problem.
The OneDrive client (or the OneDrive for Business client) both upload files in designated locations, and, based on the settings of the client, downloads/updates/diffs those files in other locations, using user permissions appropriate to the user whose account the OneDrive client is running under.
If you use OneDrive to sync files in a shared directory, those files will sync based on the permissions of the account OneDrive is running as, not with the permissions assigned to that shared directory.
Because OneDrive for Business is a OneDrive-client front to SharepointOnline (SPO), there is SOME sharing capability built in, and you can manually assign share permissions within the OneDrive for Business OR the SPOinterfaces to govern access to those shared files.
Assuming you are running some hybrid SPO/local network file share thing, you should stop. If the requirement is that people be able to access org-shared content on their mobile devices, get rid of the local network file share and just map and use regular SPO shares configured properly and synced to appropriate user's computers. If you need a local network file share, then don't "connect" it to an SPO share, because they are fundamentally different things and they will interact poorly with each other.
